# x509 and digital signature

Tags: c#, .net, security, x509certificate

I'm rewriting an application so that we can stop using the old Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.X509 from Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll and start using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.

There is one method that I can't figure out, though:

`bool Microsoft.Web.Services2.Security.X509.X509Certificate.SupportsDigitalSignature()`

I can't find its equivalent in

`System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2`.

Do I even need to test for whether a certificate supports digital signature? I don't see how it cannot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the certificate must have a private key in order to be used for signing. Use [X509Certificate2.HasPrivateKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.hasprivatekey.aspx) property to check this.

Use `X509Certificate2.Extensions` property to get access to [Key Usage extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keyusageextension.aspx). One of key usages is Digital Signature. This is what you are looking for.

Comment: On second thought, I'm on the server side having only the public key part of the client's certificate, so I must only check against the KeyUsage extension.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will want to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services3.security.tokens.securitytoken.supportsdigitalsignature.aspx)
`Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think the web services enhancements is what I need. It is described on MSDN as "WSE is an engine for applying advanced Web service protocols to SOAP messages."(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa529139.aspx) Which is not what I'll use the certificates for. (I believe the use of Microsoft.Web.Services2 was just necessary because of lacking certificate support in early .Net versions.)